# Seamingly identical mesh planes get different results with same geometry node modifier. Probably an issue with normals

Tags: geometry-nodes, normals, extrude

[image]

[image]

So here we have 2 identical mesh plane objects. Same position of the origin point, same orientation. The only difference is how they were created, The left one was creted from circle mesh and then most of the vertices were dissolved leaving just the for vertices. The right one was created as a plane. Both of these seamingly identical mesh objects were given the same geonode setum, seen here. But the result is as you can se totaly different. Noto only that but the left one, if you rotate the plane around the z axis, the profile twirls around

Comment: It probably has something to do with the tilt of curve or something like that. What makes it weird is that the start of the mesh is identical, so whay do resulting curve (from mesh to curve node)  have different normals or tilts?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to recreate your phenomenon with a Circle (set to 4 vertices) and also with a simple Plane (also 4 verts):
[image]

To avoid unwanted shifting, it seems that the Profile and the respective Frame object need to have the same Center Point and all tranforms applied and the Object Info Node needs to be set to *Relative*. Then, both Plane and Circle look identical.

[image]

Also, they show the same weird behavior when rotating:

[image]

To solve the twisting problem, you will need **two separate Profiles** and the respective Profile needs to be a Child of its own Frame:

[image]
Otherwise, as soon as the frame is moved, the change of relative distance between Profile and Frame will result in unwanted shifting and/or twisting.

Comment: Sorry, but that didn't make the 2 objects identical. If anything it made them even more different since the origin point of the profile curve is now different for each object.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. Every frame needs its own profile (but it could be 'Alt-D'-ed). I edited my post and tried to clarify what steps it took for me to get identical behavior of circle and plane.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I didn't get to this sooner, but I realized soon after I posted the question, what was causing this issue. One of the objects was rotated. Check out LaserLars's answer to understand why this different orientation of the objects would cause different behavior.[image]